# $u$ in $L^p$ implies that $u+c$ is in $L^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose that $\displaystyle\int_U|u(x)|^p\,dx<\infty$, where $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded and $p$ is a positive integer.

How can I prove that $\displaystyle\int_U|u(x)+c|^p\,dx<\infty$?  where is a real contant.

Thanks!

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with several complex variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\|u + c\|_p \le \|u\|_p + \|c\|_p.$$
Since you are on a set of finite measure, $\|c\|_p$ is finite.

Comment: To add insight to this concise answer: on a set of finite measure, the restriction to being in $L^p$ is a matter of blowing up at points; decay no longer factors in. Since adding a constant does not affect the way a function blows up, it will not affect its membership in $L^p$.